# Do I need to increase max_connections in Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, nginx

I am using this website analytics tool: [Umami](https://umami.is/docs/about)

I am currently looking at the `postgresql.conf` file and I see that `max_connections` is set to 100.

At peak times, my site may have **1000** concurrent users.

**Is Postgresql configured to support that**, or does the `max_connections` means it will only support 100 at a time and disregard the other 900 users.

Should I increase this value? Is there anything else I need to increase?

If it helps, I'm using NGINX+Ubuntu to store the Postgresql Database

Comment: You should use a connection pooler. If you application doesn't have built-in support for connection pooling, then use an external one like pgPool or pgBouncer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so Postgres can't support 1000 concurrent users?

Comment: That's really pushing it to the limits, yes. You need very capable hardware to cope with that. The upcoming version 14 will be able to handle that many users much more efficiently. But still: using a connection pooler is a **much** better (and way more scalable) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix up "concurrent application users" and "concurrent database queries". If your queries are short, you may be able to handle thousands of application users with a handful of database connections.

Use a connection pool, that way you will get the best efficiency, and you won't risk overloading the database with too many concurrent queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `postgresql.conf`

Sample: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample#L64

Few helpful commands:

```sql
SHOW max_connections;
```

default value is 100.

reset

```sql
RESET max_connections;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS

As a comment, you can use connection pool by programming language (for example, Java, JDBC): https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/datasource.html

I think it is also a good practice.